# qemu-kvm savevm very slow

Tags: gentoo, kvm, qemu

I have up to date gentoo system with kvm images located on 500 gb partition with 200 gb of free space and defragmented, running machine with Windows XP and 2gb ram, I have problem with making snapshot of runing vm.

When I try to save state via the `savevm` command using qemu monitor it starts to use 100% of disk IO and writes data very slowly (<1mb/s). It also causing very big fragmentation very fast.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

After ~half hour I have this:

```
filefrag tmp_sys.img
    tmp_sys.img: 25154 extents found
```

and it's still saving... Completely unusable.

Comment: Please, add some formatting to your question...

Comment: i am new here, what exactly wrong with formatting ?

Comment: Look how your question is looking now...

Comment: thx for hint, i will use better formatting !

Comment: apparently this is not a bug -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/741887 -- but a consequence of using default cache settings (cache=writethrough)